# Gradle invocation "completing successfully with 1 error" on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle, android-studio

So I get the following error when creating a new project on Android Studio 0.5.2 on Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit and trying to run it on a physical device:

```
Information:/home/juan/Documents/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Failed to run command:
/home/juan/Documents/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/aapt s -i
/home/juan/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication4/app/build/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/19.0.1/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png -o /home/juan/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication4/app/build/res/all/debug/drawable-hdpi/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png
  Error Code:
    127
  Output:
    /home/juan/Documents/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've got the same setup (AS 0.5.2) on a MacBook Pro and Gradle completes successfully with no errors at all, so something must be wrong. I also had to install 32-bit versions of a couple libraries to get adb working on my 64-bit Ubuntu. Maybe that's whats going on here? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** Also tried installing the following libraries:

```
$sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

No luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

fixed it by reinstalling

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
```

Thanks anyway!

Comment: The app won't let me do so for some reason.

Comment: worked on installing packages mentioned in the question and the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a 64 bit Ubuntu, and I resolved the problem by installing
the following packages

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html